# Does PHP automatically do urldecode() on $_POST?

Tags: php, post, urldecode

According to http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php, PHP does `urldecode()` on `$_GET` and on `$_REQUEST` (which contains `$_POST`).

But is directly calling `$_POST` already decoded?

Comment: Yes it is already urldecoded.

Comment: The docs explicitly say so for `$_GET`, though only in user-contrib comments for `$_POST`. http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php

Comment: Which comment Michael?

Comment: [First one on the $_POST docs](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php#87650)

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski That actually seems to be talking about the way it converts `[]` names into an array, not URL-decoding.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yes, all the parameters you access via `$_GET` and `$_POST` are decoded.

The reason the `urldecode()` documentation doesn't mention `$_POST` is because the POST data might not be URL-encoded in the first place. It depends on whether the POST data is submitted in `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` format or `multipart/form-data` format.

But all this is transparent to the application.

The documentation of [`$_GET`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) does mention this explicitly, though.

> **Note**:
>   The GET variables are passed through `urldecode()`.

Comment: From [the $_GET docs](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php): "Note: The GET variables are passed through urldecode()."

Comment: It's application/x-www-form-urlencoded  -- you missed the last d. That's 20 minutes of my life I won't get back :)

Comment: @RogerKaplan Thanks, I fixed the typo. You rarely need to write this by hand, it's usually handled automatically by APIs.

Comment: @Barmar I'd agree with you but if you're at a question about the lower level of PHP form handling, you've probably gone off-piste. I was trying to adapt an AJAX call to a PHP framework expecting a regular form...